# Real-time display of `date` changes on Linux

Tags: linux, date, busybox

On an embedded Linux device that *does not present `/dev/rtc*`*, how can I set off a console window writing the value of the Real-Time Clock to the console, on the tick, every time it changes?

Results would be like:

```
$ **someCmd**
Mon Mar 14 16:43:22 UTC 2011
Mon Mar 14 16:43:23 UTC 2011
Mon Mar 14 16:43:24 UTC 2011
Mon Mar 14 16:43:25 UTC 2011
Mon Mar 14 16:43:26 UTC 2011
```

etc.

The device is `armv5tejl` running BusyBox v1.13.3.

Comment: It assumes a non-tickless kernel, that is, there are timer ticks at HZ rate. Why do you need this?

Comment: @Maxim: I don't "need" it. I was looking at the sky and decided I wanted to know whether this can be done. I thought it would be interesting.

Comment: @x29a: Good edit, good eye. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know how much the BusyBox shell supports, but in sh you could do something like this:

```
{ while true ; do date ; sleep 0.1 ; done } | uniq
```

Comment: `sleep` on our BusyBox won't take fractions, though `{ while true ; do date ; usleep 100000 ; done } | uniq` does the job. Nice. :) Still, I wonder whether there's a solution without explicit polling? In order to gain minimum latency.

Comment: Well it's not quite what I was after, but it seems to be the closest I'll get. :) So I'll accept.

Comment: just add one 'clear;' command infront of 'date;'. Also i think sleep can just be 1. But awesome solution.

Answer (score 23):

Use  the watch commad, try this is: 
`watch -n 1 date`

Comment: It only takes integer seconds as interval, which means the result could be up to a whole 0.9999 seconds out at any given time. It's a polling approach (and not as good a polling approach as Thomas's) that does not output to console "on the tick"! Thanks, though...

Comment: Does that do it without polling? That could be the basis for a new answer :)

Comment: Using `watch -n 0.1 date` works as expected on CentOS 7, with a value update every 0.1s